# Query to remove a dash character in a MySQL database table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to run a query to update a MySQL database table to remove the dash character from a UID such as:

```
1.2.826.0.1.3680043.9.3248.152233-1.1
```

The problem is I need to do it with about 20,000 entries in the table, what would the query look like (with wildcards I guess)?

Comment: [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE TABLENAME SET
UIDCOLUMN = replace(UIDCOLUMN, '-', '')
```